# Bootstrap template admin panel login check

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I bought a responsive admin panel template built with bootstrap. I have a question:

I am using jquery on all the admin panel files to get data from a web service.

What is the best way to disallow people from accessing files of the admin panel if they are not logged in ? Let us say I have checklogin.php ? Do I have to call it on every page and then redirect them to a different login page ? And change the format of my files from .html to .php ?

Regards

Comment: Yes, to use PHP you need to have all pages in PHP format with the .php file extension.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is, to add a field to your users table (e.g. isAdmin) and make it default to 0 for all new accounts. Then give yourself a isAdmin value of **1**. Then you can simply redirect the user away before displaying the page contents if he doesn't meet certain criteria. For example..

```
// If they are not an admin (!= not equal to), kick them to the curb!
if(($_SESSION['isAdmin']) != "1") {
  header("Location: getoutofmyadminarea.php"); 

  die("Redirecting to getoutofmyadminarea.php");
}
```

To use this method you will need to initialize a user session.

You could have a seperate login page, possibly even on a subdomain if you value security, but better keep it simple if you're learning.

Answer (score 0):

What is the best way to disallow people from accessing files of the admin panel if they are not logged in ?

```
You need to use a server side authentication system. OR
You can use an HTTP authentication method,
but then you might have difficulty logging out.
```

Let us say I have checklogin.php ?

```
What will your checklogin.php file do?
Yes, you can create a server side authentication system.
```

Do I have to call it on every page and then redirect them to a different login page ?

```
No. Not necessarily on every page.
You can create a PHP session when authenticated,
and check the session to validate a user.
```

And change the format of my files from .html to .php ?

```
Well, yes. You'll need to change them to .php if you want to detect PHP sessions.
```

**A simple solution for you:**

Use [Htaccess Authentication](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/) to password protect your admin directory.
That way you wont need any server side scripting. But be warned, there are no efficient methods to signout a user.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SESSION to check if user is logged in , if not ..redirect to other page or display an error message.
You have to check the session on every page you want.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION["logged"] != true) {
    echo("Access is denied!");

}else{
    echo "Welcome admin";
}
?>
```